# Interleave list with fixed element

Tags: python, list

I know that I can interleave two python lists with:

```
[elem for pair in zip(*lists) for elem in pair]
```

Now I need to interleave a list with a fixed element like:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
#  python magic 
output = [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One really straightforward solution is:

```
[elem for x in list for elem in (x, 0)][:-1]
```

Comment: I believe this is the simplest and most clear solution.

Comment: @aitchnyu if you have the nested structure `list = [(1,2), (3,4)]` and you want to flatten it you can use `[elem for pair in list for elem in pair]` so you take each `pair` and then you take each `elem` in the pair. In the code above you don't have the pairs, but you create a pair `(x, 0)` for each element `x` in the original list, then you leverage the same strategy as before in order to flatten the list, obtaining `[x1, 0, x2, 0, x3, 0]`. Then you remove the trailing `0` using `[:-1]`.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following itertools magic:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, chain, izip
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(izip(l[:-1], repeat(0)))) + l[-1:]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import izip, repeat

start = [1, 2, 3, 4]

print [i for j in izip(start, repeat(0)) for i in j][:-1]
```

Comment: I have noticed that this attaches an extra 0 at the end of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Python's `sum` function can be used on arbitrary datatypes that support addition by setting the `start` parameter appropriately. ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum))

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4]
fixed = 0
output = sum([[elem, fixed] for elem in input], [])[:-1]  # to drop the last `fixed`
```

Or if you don't like the idea of using the addition operator with lists:

```
input = [1, 2, 3, 4]
fixed = 0
output = []
for elem in input:
    output.extend([elem, fixed])
output = output[:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> newlst = [0]*((len(lst) * 2) - 1)
>>> newlst[::2] = lst
>>> newlst
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

It may not be a one-liner, but it works. Furthermore, my [time tests](http://repl.it/m5z) seem to show that it's the fastest solution so far. In function form, this is:

```
def interzero(lst):
    newlst = [0]*((len(lst) * 2) - 1)
    newlst[::2] = lst
    return newlst
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `reduce` function of `functools`.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y, 0], [1,2,3,4], [])[:-1]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(chain(*zip(lst, [0]*(len(lst)-1)))) + [lst[-1]]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```